# Parceljs bundle issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, parceljs

I am bundling my app with parceljs and hitting this particular issue which I am not able to resolve at the moment.

I have 1 component which is referencing a image like

```
import defaultImage from '/path/to/image';
```

and using it like below in the code

```
<img src={defaultImage} />
```

I am reusing that component where tree look like this
[image]

Parcel build process does not throw any error and if I follow the flow as
1. Navigate to /component1 (Image is displayed)

but when I navigate to /component2 I get the Module not found error for image.

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'assets/imgs/default_article.png'
at newRequire (VM191 src.80dfb952.js:39)
at newRequire (searchPage.363c2bd8.js:31)
at newRequire (VM191 src.80dfb952.js:31)
at newRequire (VM191 src.80dfb952.js:23)
at localRequire (VM191 src.80dfb952.js:55)
at Object.parcelRequire.../components/misc/articleThumbnail.js.react (VM191 src.80dfb952.js:76489)
at newRequire (VM191 src.80dfb952.js:49)
at localRequire (VM191 src.80dfb952.js:55)
at Object.parcelRequire.../components/feed/feeditem.js.react (VM191 src.80dfb952.js:77133)
at newRequire (VM191 src.80dfb952.js:49)
```

Has anyone paced this issue with Parcel and any fixes?

Comment: Just a hunch, have you tried requiring the image with an [absolute path](https://parceljs.org/module_resolution.html#module-resolution) (i.e with a `/` prefix in your path)? `import image from '/absolute/path/to/image'`.

Comment: yes I have but I still get the same issue as the component is same

Comment: I had a similar problem running parcel locally, and clearing the `.parcel-cache` folder seems to have solved it for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I have been able to get around the issue is to import the common images in Main.js and then pass them down to components as part of props.

Comment: Thanks for this it works! Another solution which may be cleaner is using context: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html